# fetching n level deep relation in hibernate/gorm

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have implemented a Category domain which supports n level deep nesting.

The Category table contains a parent_id which is nothing but a id of Category table only.

```
public class Category {

String name;
//Reference to parent category
Category parentCategory;
//Child categories if this Category is a parent (Should I keep this in domain or remove it?)
Set categories;
}
```

A > B > C

M > N > O > P > Q

The above hierarchies can be created by setting 
id of A as parent_id of B, id of B as parent_id of C
id of M as parent_id of N, id of N as parent id of O and so on..

Now I want to display a tree like structure of all the categories (using jsTree). What will be the best way to fetch the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hasMany relationship to self for the child sub-categories.

```
public class Category {
   String name;
   //Reference to parent category
   Category parentCategory;
   static hasMany = [subCategories: Category]
}
```

Now you can either do a lazy fetch on the parent to get the child elements by using a '.' operation on the parent OR use a criteria to fetch all the child elements eagerly (provided this is inexpensive).

Note: We would only need the `parentCategory` in order to move up the tree from leaf node towards the root. If only one way traversal is needed then the `hasMany` mapping should be sufficient.